# Sending email with docx attachment using Python 3.x

Tags: python, smtp, docx

I am sending an email using python with Gmail (which shows it in the sent folder on Gmail) to my Yahoo email address with a docx attachment.

It all seems to work ok except when it arrives in Gmail it has the attachment file name with `__io.BufferedReader name='myfile.docx'_`

Raw Message arrived at destination at Yahoo shows:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= <_io.BufferedReader name='myfile.docx'>
```

How do I fix it so the filename doesn't have `<_io.BufferedReader...`  etc? I am guessing it's fixing the header?  Also, why is the `content-transfer-encoding:base64` repeated in the header?

```
        subject = "this is the subject line"
        message = MIMEMultipart()
        message["Subject"] = subject
        message["From"] = sender_email
        message["To"] = receiver_email

        body = 'This is the body of the email'

        message.attach(MIMEText(body))

        attach_file = open("myfile.docx", 'rb') # Open the file as binary mode

        payload = MIMEApplication(attach_file.read(),
                        'vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')

        encoders.encode_base64(payload)

        payload.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                            "attachment; filename= %s" % attach_file)

        message.attach(payload)

#for SSL 465 port - wont work yet on gmx but works on gmail

        context = ssl.create_default_context()

        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port,context=context) as server:

            try:
#                server.ehlo()  this is for not needed for gmail but is for gmx TLS
#                server.starttls() this is not needed for gmail SSL but is for gmx TLS 
                server.login(sender_email, password)
                server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string())
                self.statusBar().showMessage('Email Sent.')
                server.quit()

            except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
                self.statusBar().showMessage('Email Not Sent. Authentication Failure.')
                server.quit()

            except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
                self.statusBar().showMessage(f"SMTP exception {e}")
                server.quit()
```

Comment: As an aside. it looks like your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

ok fixed it myself, yet again. So simple, it's embarrassing I missed it. Anyway, if you're having trouble with NO NAME as the attachment (or__io.BufferedReader name='myfile.docx'_) when it arrives at it's destination just add .name to the end of the attachment file name when you're adding the header.   Not that I could see many examples with that reference here.
Also latest versions doesn't need to call the encoders specifically, or you will get the double "encoded" in the raw header.

```
#       encoders.encode_base64(payload)
# already encoded, so didn't need this line above
        payload.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                           'attachment',filename='%s' % attach_file.name)
```

Comment: `'%s' % string` is just a really clumsy way to write `string` (or `str(string)` if the variable isn't actually a string already).